# Jquery Cycle plugin, how to syntax cycle duration

Tags: jquery, cycle

i just used the jQuery Cycle plugin on a website.

I'm HORRIBLE with jquery syntaxing so I dont know the correct way to tell Cycler to fade my images every 2-3 seconds instead of 5 seconds here's the code in my index.html `<head>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });
});
```

please, id love to know how to correctly tell jquery 3 seconds and cose the statement aswell.

Im just so bad with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`timeout` option](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 2500 // milliseconds = 2.5 seconds
    });
});
```